# Google Custom Search engine for my site doesn't seem to actually crawl my site

Tags: google-custom-search, google-sites

I added a custom Google search engine to my site (which happens to be a Google site). But when I search, nothing from my site comes up — just a few sponsored Google results. I've set up the search engine to search my site https://sites.google.com/view/mysite/* (not the real name) specifically. What's not working?

My guess was that Google itself hasn't yet crawled my site — but when I tried to submit my site to Google, I couldn't because Google requires you to either upload an HTML file or add some code between , and Google Sites doesn't let you do that. You'd think they'd automatically crawl their own sites though, no?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you checked search entire web which limits the search of your site .Basically those sites that appear have excellent SEO than your site and your site is also crawled under those multiple retrieved pages you see but its hard to land  on it